What should I do with RCS after finding non-linearity in a cox model
Hi I am conducting cox regression analysis.
I found out with RCS macro on SAS that our variable 'systolic bp' has non-linearity issue.
So, in this case how should I report the results?
Our main interest is not this factor. systolic bp is just for adjusting in the multivariable cox regression analysis.
Below is the result of the cox regression model with restricted cubic spline applied (5 knots)
Thank you in advance!


You've done a good job assuming there are no other continuous predictors (they should have also been splined; don't look at whether nonlinear terms are 'significant' or not).  The 4 and 3 d.f. chunk tests are important summaries.
